# WebAPI 2 attribute routing enable session state

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

We figured out how to enable session state with webapi [Sample here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/513522/Providing-session-state-in-ASP-NET-WebAPI)

Now we have WebApi 2 attribute routing, so we no longer have route object to inject custom handler.

**Is there any way of enabling session state with attribute routing?**

Answer (score 7):

You need to add this to **global.asax**

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest() 
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

Then you could access the session through:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: I tried this but there is a serious flaw to this approach: the session does exist however the SessionID differs for every request.

Answer (score -1):

in the global.asax

```
Private Sub WebApiApplication_PostAuthorizeRequest(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PostAuthorizeRequest
     System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required)
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the [SessionStateUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateutility%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to get the session state. Just call:

```cs
var session = SessionStateUtility.GetHttpSessionStateFromContext(HttpContext.Current)
```

Api controllers are designed for restful services and should generally be stateless. Not loading the session every time is one of the things that makes them lighter weight.

Comment: @RolandoCC: You will need to write `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);` line in `Application_PostAuthorizeRequest` event in `global.asax`. [Check this answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22491093/1951058)