# Web Api 2 Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I cannot get session data from while in web api 2. I have verified that the cookie is sending in fiddler.

I know that web api 2 best practice is to be stateless, but due to requirements on a project it is now necessary to be state-full.

I have tried this link.
[WebAPI 2 attribute routing enable session state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758221/webapi-2-attribute-routing-enable-session-state)

```
var session = SessionStateUtility.GetHttpSessionStateFromContext(HttpContext.Current)
```

With the above solution I am getting a null exception on that function.

I also tried replicating the way of doing this the way you would in the old web api by modifying the requesthandler from the route, but that is not available in web api 2.

I currently set some session variables in mvc5. This works and the session stays, but anytime I am trying to use session while in web api 2 the below is null.

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: You need to not only confirm that the cookie is sent; you need to confirm that it is the _same_ session ID cookie as used in the MVC application. I bet you have two different session ids.

Comment: They are not different. I have also verified that they are the same sessionID.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I have the situation you're talking about -- I get different session ids. Why does that happen?

Answer (score 53):

Add

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest() 
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.Required);
}
```

to global.asax

Comment: Sweet worked a treat.  Will this work on Windows Azure websites in a web farm using Redis or something?

Comment: This event doesn't fire for me?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am testing correctly, but for me the sessionId is different when retrieving in an mvc controller and an api controller, which makes it useless for me.

Answer (score 1):

If PostAuthorizeRequest doesn't work, then try BeginRequest.

Comment: I think he was talking about the @Dejo answer