# use session in Web Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have read that an effective way to use enable session in web api 2 is like so:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthorizeRequest()
  {
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
  }
```

I have also created a class that inherits from `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` and overrides the `OnAuthorization` method.

But this event is never called - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK Web**API**2 should be stateless therefore use different authorization approach.

Comment: That is true.. Web API should be "RESTFUL" and therefore stateless.

Comment: I'm aware the http is stateless. Doesn't really help me much though...

Comment: what is your usecases for needing sessions? personally it's the first thing I turn off on any new asp.net projects - its a performance bottleneck and only hampers scale-out in future if you need to.

Comment: Thanks MacB. We currently have a lot of web services that require session, and due to the use of the <WebMethod(enableSession:=True)> attribute the services have read/write access to session, which is causing session state blocking. In web api I believe it is possible to grant read only access to session, which wouldn't block. The idea is to migrate to web api to improve performance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WebAPI 2 attribute routing enable session state](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19758221/webapi-2-attribute-routing-enable-session-state)

Comment: Its not a duplicate - My questions contains the answer given in that post, I'm just unsure why this method isn't called.

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating a HttpModule:

```
public class WebApiSessionModule : IHttpModule
{
    protected virtual void OnPostAuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        if (this.IsWebApiRequest(context))
        {
            context.SetSessionStateBehavior(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to add this to your web.config in

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
```